# Finding groups of sequential, identical values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, gaps-and-islands

If I have a table that looks like this:

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
| SalesPerson | SalesYear | SalesMonth | TotalSales |
+-------------+-----------+------------+------------|
| Dave        | 2011      | 1          |27          |
| Meg         | 2012      | 7          |162         |
| Randy       | 2011      | 3          |0           |
| Julio       | 2013      | 8          |15          |
| Bob         | 2014      | 12         |0           |
| Mary        | 2012      | 5          |20          |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

And I wanted to find periods of inactivity, let's say at least three months in a row where a sales person had no sales, how would I do that? I don't just want a list of all the months with no sales; I need to see prolonged periods of inactivity. Multiple sequential zeros. I can't figure it out.

Comment: Any chance of providing better data? As it stands, each salesperson is listed only once, so they technically all qualify.

Answer (score 0):

First step is to transform year and month into datetime.
Next we should find left and right boundaries of each period of inactivity in partion of SalesPerson.
Then we sort left boundaries and right boundaries to determine how to connect them.
And finally join left and right boundaries.

```
--------------creating test data------------------------------------
    declare @t table(SalesPerson varchar(max), SalesYear int, SalesMonth int, TotalSales int)

     select replicate('0', 2 - len(cast(3 as varchar))) + '3'

    insert into @t(SalesPerson, SalesYear , SalesMonth , TotalSales)
    select 'Dave', 2011, 1, 27 union all
    select 'Meg', 2012, 7, 162 union all
    select 'Randy', 2011, 3, 0 union all
    select 'Julio', 2013, 8, 15 union all
    select 'Bob', 2014, 12, 0 union all
    select 'Mary', 2012, 5, 20 union all
    select 'Mary', 2012, 6, 0 union all
    select 'Mary', 2012, 7, 0 union all
    select 'Mary', 2012, 8, 20 union all
    select 'Mary', 2012, 9, 20 
-------------------------------------------

    ;with cte as
    (
        select SalesPerson
            , cast(cast(SalesYear as varchar) + replicate('0', 2 - len(cast(SalesMonth as varchar))) + cast(SalesMonth as varchar) + '01' as datetime) as dt
            , TotalSales
            , row_number() over (partition by SalesPerson order by  cast(cast(SalesYear as varchar) + replicate('0', 2 - len(cast(SalesMonth as varchar))) + cast(SalesMonth as varchar) + '01' as datetime)) as rn
            , row_number() over (partition by SalesPerson order by  cast(cast(SalesYear as varchar) + replicate('0', 2 - len(cast(SalesMonth as varchar))) + cast(SalesMonth as varchar) + '01' as datetime) desc)  as rnd
        from @t 
    ),
    l as
    (
    select *, row_number() over(partition by SalesPerson order by dt) n
    from cte t1
    where TotalSales = 0
        and (
            exists
            (
                select * 
                from cte 
                where t1.SalesPerson = SalesPerson 
                    and dateadd(mm,-1, t1.dt) = dt
                    and TotalSales > 0
            )
            or rn = 1
            )
    ),
    r as
    (
    select *,row_number() over(partition by SalesPerson order by dt) n
    from cte t1
    where TotalSales = 0
        and (
            exists
            (
                select * 
                from cte 
                where t1.SalesPerson = SalesPerson 
                    and dateadd(mm,1, t1.dt) = dt
                    and TotalSales > 0
            )
            or rnd = 1
            )
    )
    select l.SalesPerson, l.dt as dateStart, r.dt as dateEnd
    from l 
        join r on l.n = r.n
            and l.SalesPerson = r.SalesPerson
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to account for multiple dead periods. For instance, if Bob has four down months from Feb 2011 to Jun 2011 and then again from Apr 2014 to Jul 2014, only the second period gets noticed with this query.

Comment: What you mean when say dead periods? Is it possible that record with period between another periods for same person not exist in table?

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of a period of inactivity is a little vague, e.g. do you take into account hire/fire dates? The following code implements one interpretation that doesn't require recursion.

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Sales as Table (
  SalesPerson VarChar(10), SalesYear Int, SalesMonth Int, TotalSales Int );
insert into @Sales ( SalesPerson, SalesYear, SalesMonth, TotalSales ) values
  ( 'Dave', 2011, 1, 27) ,
  ( 'Meg', 2012, 7, 162 ),
  ( 'Randy', 2011, 3, 0 ),
  ( 'Julio', 2013, 8, 15 ),
  ( 'Bob', 2014, 12, 0 ),
  ( 'Mary', 2012, 5, 20 ),
  ( 'William', 2014, 1, 30 ),
  ( 'William', 2014, 2, 0 ),
  ( 'William', 2014, 4, 10 ),
  ( 'William', 2014, 6, 3 ),
  ( 'William', 2014, 7, 90 ),
  ( 'William', 2014, 12, 5 );
select * from @Sales;

-- Analyze it.
with
  -- Get only the nonzero sales rows and combine the year/month into a single integer.
  NonZeroSales as (
    select SalesPerson, SalesYear * 12 + SalesMonth as CombinedMonth, TotalSales
      from @Sales
      where TotalSales <> 0 ),
  -- Add row numbers for each sales person.
  NonZeroSalesWithRN as (
    select SalesPerson, CombinedMonth, TotalSales,
      Row_Number() over ( partition by SalesPerson order by CombinedMonth ) as RN
      from NonZeroSales )
  -- Match adjacent rows for each sales person.
  --   If there is a gap of three or more months then indicate it in a status column.
  select L.SalesPerson,
    Floor( L.CombinedMonth / 12 ) as SalesYear, L.CombinedMonth % 12 as SalesMonth,
    L.TotalSales,
    case when R.CombinedMonth - L.CombinedMonth > 3 then 'Gap > 3 Months' else 'Okay' end as SalesStatus
    from NonZeroSalesWithRN as L inner join
      NonZeroSalesWithRN as R on R.SalesPerson = L.SalesPerson and R.RN = L.RN + 1;
  -- Tip: To see what is going on, or debug, multiple CTEs replace the last select with
  --   select * from NonZeroSales
  --   select * from NonZeroSalesWithRN
```

Answer (score -1):

HAVING (Transact-SQL) is your answer.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx

Misread the question at first.